# Is there a way to narrow the authorization scope when using azure management library?

Tags: azure, x509certificate, x509certificate2, azure-automation, azure-management-api

I've followed Brady Gaster's tutorial [here](http://www.bradygaster.com/post/managing-web-sites-from-web-sites-using-the-windows-azure-management-libraries-for-net) to be able to use  `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.WebSites`.

This approach uses a certificate uploaded to Azure, with `X509Certificate2` + `CertificateCloudCredentials`. What worries me is this certificate pretty much gives the user carte blanche for everything. I don't need that much power.

Is there a way to narrow the scope? I only need to be able to add a hostname and bind an SSL certificate for one Azure web app, preferably my credentials would allow me to only do that (or at least touch only the one web app).

Answer (score 1):

> What worries me is this certificate pretty much gives the user carte
>   blanche for everything.

You're very correct. Essentially with the certificate, you're giving away keys of your Azure kingdom to the certificate holder (in a manner of speaking).

> Is there a way to narrow the scope?

Definitely! Do take a look at [`Azure Resource Manager`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/) and [`Role Based Access Control (RBAC)`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-what-is/). With RBAC, you can assign granular permissions on your Azure Resources.

I have not used Management Client Library but I believe you would need to use [`TokenCloudCredentials`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.tokencloudcredentials.aspx) instead of `CertificateCloudCredentials`.